# How to Load CSV file into Apex 5 for particular columns?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have table  with three columns x (Foreign Key),y(Primary Key),z  and also csv file with  only two columns  data  y,z as shown in images https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFOoj.jpg (Please copy and paste link)which has to uploaded into table.Here I fill x column for all the rows with constant value ‘20’.i have used Data loading wizard to do this in Apex 5.
Problem:
In the first step I loaded this table and then In next step you can see that I have to do column mapping .Here I get only two columns y(Mileage),z(Ratio) because I have only two columns in the excel and first column x i  want to map with null values here(Problem 1).

In the next step I have added process in the Datavalidation to update column x to fill that constant value as shown in images. But you could see p_attr_number =1 makes first column to be updated with 20 value.Here I need my first column x to be filled with constant value 20(Problem 2).Please Give me some suggestions on this for solving this problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for problem 1 you can choose x column as nullable yes by editing your colum in object browser -> your table -> modify column -> nullabe field to NULL (do not reguire a value) so when you upload data it will not fill third column if you map 2 columns (althıugh you do not see the column name in wizards)

for problem 2 i am assuming that all fields in your database has data so you you can add a page process for giving new values to the uploaded data which has null x columns

1 go to 4th page 'Data Load Results' which created by data wizard

2 click add a page process button

3 choose pl/sql

4 give a name and choose on submit - after computations and validations

5 enter an update command which suits your needs as below

```
update your_table_name
set 
x=20
where x is null;
```

6 write your success messages

7 choose finish button in option "when button presses"

8 create process

9 add a Branch button in Branches

10 give a name click next

11 enter the page you want to go after data load

12 choose finish button in option "when button presses"

13 go to finish button and choose submit in Action When Button Clicked -> action

by adding this process and branch

1st system will insert data to table

2nd it will update all the null x values to the static values in your table

3rd it will return to the page you want

Comment: Hi Thank you for response.I tried your solution and it doesnt work for me because process is not updating values in the backend .Moreover X is foreign key and i cannot make it as nullable.could you please some other suggestions.I see clearly the problem is with column mapping .If i dont have even one column it  doesnt get loaded into table and X is a column which is in First position so its pretty confusing for me.